# Erro ao formatar data em C#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando formatar uma data:

`string s = linha.data.ToString("yyyyMMdd");`

mas estou recebendo um erro no `ToString()`

> No overload for Method 'ToString' takes 1 argument

Alguma dica?

**EDITADO**

No meu campo data, quando eu passo o mouse em cima dele, aparece assim: `DateTime? bpiUltrassom.data {get; set;}`

Não sei porque aparece essa interrogação depois do `DateTime`

Comment: Mas não quero usar os traços, quero do jeito que está no código: anomesdia

Comment: `DateTime?` é o tipo `DateTime` que permite `Null`. 
Veja: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A interrogação aparece porque sua propriedade DateTime pode ser nula. E um DateTime nulo não possuí o método `ToString(String)`, por isso apresenta apresenta erro.

Para resolver seu problema, substitua o tipo de sua propriedade de `DateTime?` para `DateTime` apenas, ou trate seu valor antes da conversão e utilize o `.Value`.
Ex:

```
string dataFormatada = (data != null? data.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução encontrada:

```
string s = linha.data.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser feito da seguinte forma.

```
string s = linha.data.ToString().ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```